# latest version of scalatestplus

Tags: scalatest, playframework-2.6

How could I find available versions of `scalatestplus`? I checked [this](https://github.com/playframework/scalatestplus-play#releases) page but it only tells the compatibility of `scalatestplus` with `Play`. How can I find which releases are available in `3.1.x`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can see all the versions of `scalatestplus-play` via

- [Maven Central repository](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.scalatestplus.play/scalatestplus-play)
- [Github releases page](https://github.com/playframework/scalatestplus-play/releases)

Currently, 3.1.0, 3.1.1, and 3.1.2 have been released.